# Reading file and returning data (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am new to JavaScript and general websites - so excuse me if this question sounds a bit basic.

However, the idea is to have a popup message displaying on every page saying some information. Since the website is static - if at a later date we want to change the message we'll have to edit every single page.

To simplify this, I've been trying to include a simple text document on the server.

The page will read the text document and display the message.

So, we just edit the text document and the message displayed on the page will thus change.

My code is so:

```
   <div class="sticky-box" id="x">
        <div class="sticky-inner">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.4/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            window.addEvent("domready",function(){
                var csvRequest = new Request({
                url:"text.txt",
                onSuccess:function(response){                           
                        document.write(response);                       
                    }
                }).send(); 
            });
            </script>
    </div>
```

Whilst, it successfully reads the document - it displays the text instead of the web page. In short, I get "Some example text" on the page but absoulty nothing else.

Any one have any ideas why?

Is there an easier way to do this?

Note: Redoing the website is *not* an option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `document.write(response)` you should create a container say a div or span element on your page and write the data in that container. When you use `documen.write()` after page loading is complete, the browser opens a new document and replaces the content of current document.

Something like below code should help:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.4/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    window.addEvent("domready",function(){
    var csvRequest = new Request({
    url:"text.txt",
    onSuccess:function(response){                           
    document.getElementById("sticky_inner").innerHTML= response;                       
    }
    }).send(); 
    });
</script>
<div class="sticky-box" id="x">
    <div class="sticky-inner" id="sticky_inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `document.write(response)`. `document.write` will simply create a blank document and write the content on it. You should instead use, for example, a `div` element and write 
the data in it.

More on [document.write](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/06/three_javascrip_1.html)